Route user back to home after browser refresh a child route
Having trouble getting this one, basically I have an app with 4 parents (separate dashboards), and within them a home screen and pages of a form that the user fills out
If user is inside one of the form pages and clicks browser refresh I want them to get routed back to the dashboards home page, also if they try to type the path manually I want to redirect them the same
From my reading it looks like I have the routing set correctly but on refresh I just come back to the same page
So wondering if I can do this with just routing config, or do I need to create a resolver?
Here's my main route simplified down:
@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        [
            /* page list  */
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard] },
            
            {
                path: 'roleSelector',
                component: EstablishmentSelectorComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard],
            },
            { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
            {
                path: 'dasha',
                loadChildren: () => import("../dashA/dashA.module").then((m) => m.DashAModule),
                canActivate: [RoleGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'dashb',
                loadChildren: () => import("../dashB/dashB.module").then((m) => m.DashBModule),
                canActivate: [RoleGuard],
                data: { role: ["FH"] },
            },
            { path: "", redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: "full" },
        ],
        { onSameUrlNavigation: "reload",
            initialNavigation: environment.useAuth ? 'disabled' : 'enabledNonBlocking',
            useHash: environment.useAuth ? true : false }
    ),
],
exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

Due to security we use I had to use the hash method and disable initial navigation in order to grab the tokens, my dev testing is with these disabled
User starts at Login screen, if they have multiple Roles they get the RoleSelector screen, upon selecting they are sent to the appropriate dashboard (there's more than just these 2)
The resulting path is eg. '/dasha/home' or '/dashb/home'
When clicking on one of the form pages, path is then '/dasha/page1'
Here's one of the child routes:
Module:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(dashARoute)
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashAComponent,
    Page1Component,
    Page2Component
  ],
})
export class DashAModule { }

Route
The canDeactivate is just to stop the user from navigating away from the form pages and display a popup asking them if they are sure they wish to navigate away losing unsaved changes, in a browser refresh scenario the guard isn't called
export const dashARoute: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'home', 
        component: DashAComponent,
        canActivate: [RoleGuard],
        canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard]
    },
    { path: 'page1', component:  Page1Component, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard], runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'},
    { path: 'page2', component:  Page2Component, canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard]},
    { path: '',redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full' }

]

***Edit - I did some chatting with ChatGPT and learned about resolvers, it took some time to work it all out but have come up with this, it seems to be handling the refreshes well and manually entering the child route paths. Looking for any comments on if this is a good approach
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RefreshRedirectResolver {
constructor(private router: Router) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  
  const firstChildRoute = route.firstChild;
  const isChildRoute = firstChildRoute?.routeConfig?.path &&
                        firstChildRoute?.routeConfig?.path !== 'home';
  
    if (isChildRoute) {
        this.router.navigate([this.getTargetHomePath(route.data.role)]);
        return of(false); // Cancel current route activation
    }
    return of(true); // Allow route activation
}

private getTargetHomePath(roles: string[]): string {
    if (roles.includes("CW")) {
        return 'dashA/home;
    } else if (roles.includes("FH")) {
        return 'dashB/home';
    } else {
        return 'login'; // Default fallback if no specific role matches
    }
}

}
Added to my route:
            {
                path: 'dasha',
                loadChildren: () => import("../dashA/dashA.module").then((m) => m.DashAModule),
                canActivate: [RoleGuard],
                resolve: { refreshRedirect: RefreshRedirectResolver },
                data: { role: ["CW"] },
            },

